# Unable to set Outlook 2013 mailserver credentials via credetial manager

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, passwords, microsoft-outlook-2013, credentials-manager

I have a small business with 6 win7 computers. All computers run a local Outlook 2013 with 1 to 4 email accounts. Now every once in a while the mail server password changes so outlook prompts for a password the next time a user checks his/her mail.
I don't want the users entering passwords so I was thinking of using a script to add the new credentials to the credentials manager. 
But that doesn't seem to be the place where outlook stores it's credentials... I have tried adding the mail server with the right credentials to the vault but outlook still asks for a password. It's like it is not checking the vault for credentials.
anyone an idea how I could do this?
I know it's not the most ideal setup but I stil hoping for some workaround.

Cheers,
Robert.

Comment: Not good at coding, but found this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-add-credentials-to-c8e9bd5f

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for helping! Scripting is not the problem though, the problem is I cant figure out where Outlook 2013 stores it’s credentials.